# Interval on parametric curves

Tags: parametric, curves, plane-curves

I have to plot the graph of
$$\gamma(t)=(4\tan(t),9\sec(t))$$
for $t\in[0,\pi/2)\cup[\pi,3\pi/2)$.

I know the curve is an hyperbola, but I'd like to know if this interval of $t$ makes some difference in the graph itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the parametric curve $\gamma$ is a part of the hyperbola,
$$\frac{y^2}{9^2}-\frac{x^2}{16^2}=1$$
For $t\in[0,\pi/2)$ we get the branch in the first quadrant and for $t\in[\pi,3\pi/2)$ we obtain the branch in the fourth quadrant. These two branches are symmetric with respect to the line $y=0$.

Comment: That's what I thought. For $t$ in these intervals, $x>0$, so graphically, I only get this part?

Comment: @mvfs314 For $t\in[0,\pi/2)\cup[\pi,3\pi/2)$ you get only half of the whole hyperbola, that is the part for $x\geq 0$ which consist of two disconnected branches.